# Writing a generic function to perform an operation

Tags: java

I am trying to make logic in which user will enter the year ( for example 2102, 2001, 1992, etc. ) and the return value  will be

```
Range     | Return-value  
1600-1699 | 2  
1700-1799 | 5    
1800-1899 | 3  
1900-1999 | 1  
2000-2099 | 2  
2100-2199 | 5  
2200-2299 | 3  
2300-2399 | 1  
2400-2499 | 2
```

And the series will continue…

Example 1: Suppose user entered 1991 which comes in 1900-1999, the program will output return value = 1 (from the table). I want to make an independent logic for this.

Example 2: If user entered 2521 which comes in 2500-2599 range then output value according to the series(2,5,3,1) will be "5".

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is there any pattern behind `2,5,3,1`? Or does one have to know that 1600-1699 starts with 2 and from then on the series continues?

Comment: Pretty sure you are going to need to at least make an attempt to write code. People will be more likely to help you.

Comment: What do you mean "generic"? Because I don't see any need for handling multiple types from this descrption. Plus, different languages have very different features. The actual solutions can be *very* different

Comment: No there is no pattern behind 2,5,3,1 its the series 1600-1699 thats starting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested in c#, but should also work in java - solution with modulo operator (%) and generic - it will work for any dates.
First it divides by 100 and then uses the modulo operator - since your key order is regular each 400 years it will also work for other dates than 1600-2500.

```
private int getKeyOf(int year)
{
    switch (year / 100 % 4)
    {
        case 0:
            return 2;
        case 1:
            return 5;
        case 2:
            return 3;
        case 3:
            return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By dividing a positive integer by 100, you will get the 2 first digits. Then, in gives in Java:

```
protected int getKeyOf(int year) {
    switch (year / 100) {
    case 16:
        return 2;
    case 17:
        return 5;
    case 18:
        return 3;
    case 19:
        return 1;
    default:
        return -1;
    }
}
```